# Merge QgsMessageBar with ui file ?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgis

I try merge QgsMessageBar with ma ui file

```
from ui_file import Ui_File
class MyClass(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.bar = QgsMessageBar()
        self.ui = Ui_File()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.run)
    def run(self):
        self.bar.pushMessage("Hello", "World", level=QgsMessageBar.INFO)
```

When I change 'bar' to 'ui' I get error:
 'Ui_File' object has no attribute 'pushMessage'

Something is missing in ui file?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your example looks fine as it is, but you need to add the message-bar to the layout of the dialog.

How you do this will depend on what kind of layout the dialog has, and where you want the message-bar to appear. If the layout is `QVBoxLayout`, and you want the message-bar at the bottom of the dialog, just do:

```
    self.layout().addWidget(self.bar)
```

and to put it at the top of the dialog, you would do:

```
    self.layout().insertWidget(0, self.bar)
```

However, if the layout is a `QHBoxLayout` or `QGridLayout`, you will probably have to alter things in Qt Designer to get things to work properly. In particular, `QGridLayout` has no method for inserting widgets, so you would have to leave a space for the message-bar if you want it at the top of the dialog. You may also need to ensure that the message-bar spans the full width of the dialog. See the docs for [QGridLayout.addWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) for more details.

For a `QHBoxLayout` it's much easier - just put the existing layout inside a `QVBoxLayout` layout, and proceeed as above.